# Why is my "locale" not respecting default locale?

Tags: ubuntu, locale

On my Ubuntu 20.04LTS system, whenever I run `locale`:

```
$ locale
...
LC_MESSAGES=C
...
```

In spite of my `/etc/default/locale/`:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
...
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
```

Why is `LC_MESSAGES` "C" when I'm checking it via `locale`?

Comment: Not sure. Working here on 20.04 and 22.04 both. Have you fully updated your system? Is your clock correctly set?  Is the Date correct?

Comment: It's still on **20.04** as stated. But I think it's related to something else, so upgrade won't solve this. Yes, clock, date are both correct (synced via NTP).

Answer (score 1):

"Default" implies that there are other, higher-priority settings which `locale` respects first.

The locale is **not** read directly from /etc/default – it is only read from environment variables `$LC_MESSAGES` and such, while the file you're editing is only used to set up those environment variables **at login time.** What you see in `env|grep ^LC` is more or less what will be printed by `locale`.

Usually the file is read very early during the login process (via PAM), so the resulting environment variables can be overridden from various other sources. For example, you might've set LC_MESSAGES manually, or your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile may be `export`ing different values, or you logged in through GNOME and it retrieved the per-user settings from GSettings<sup>1</sup>. For SSH connections, if the client has "SendEnv" enabled, it might be sending the client-side `$LC_*` variables to the server which will override whatever PAM has set up.

Finally, if the `$LC_ALL` environment variable happens to be set (regardless of where it comes from), it will have priority over *all* other `$LC_*` settings.

---

<sup>1</sup> `dconf-editor org.gnome.system.locale`